# Can I delete a post of mine via the app?

Tags: support

I cannot seem to find the delete button on the app (Android phone).

I clicked on the three dots on a post of mine and I just got the option to flag it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app, unfortunately, is officially unsupported by Stack Exchange. So it is missing all sorts of functionality.

The answer is to use a browser on your phone. I use Chrome and for most things it is pretty good. For moderation duties I usually have to set it in desktop mode, though, which enables all the features.

Comment: Is it really unsupported? Since when?

Comment: Two or three years now.